# mysql update query not working?

Tags: php, mysql, html

**Edit: Now fixed! Thank you for your help!**

Sorry for the beginner questions, I'm creating a simple page to edit another page for my teams website.

This is the code I'm using, but it's not updating the database.

Incorrect code:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET `pagename` = $pagename, `pagedesc` = $pagedesc, 
`agekey` = $pagekey, `pagecont` = $pagecont WHERE `pages_id` = $pages_id") or die(mysql_error());
```

**Correct code:**

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET pagename = '$pagename', pagedesc = '$pagedesc', pagekey = '$pagekey', pagecont = '$pagecont' WHERE pages_id = $pages_id") or die(mysql_error());
```

Using `` did not work at all. But adding  or die(mysql_error()); to my query helped. I should have thought of that first! :)

Comment: extra ',' in your update statement

Comment: You should use ` around your field names rather than ', and you should quote string field data. Also, please make sure that you protect against SQL injection. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) Do some reasearch on the subject and learn how to prevent it.

Comment: There's too much wrong with the method to know where to start. The query is broken (Just echo it out and you'll see). You're not using PDO. You're not protecting *at all* against injections. Why "try that next"? There's no point learning bad things first just to unlearn them later.

Comment: Hi @DhirajBodicherla - I removed the , before the WHERE but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm trying to learn. Please don't flame me. I know this code is far from perfect, but I'm trying :(

Comment: @ try replacing '(single quote) with `(accent) or  remove it in all fields and put single quote for all variables which has string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't your mysql query should be

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET pagename = '$pagename', pagedesc = '$pagedesc', pagekey = '$pagekey', pagecont = '$pagecont' WHERE pages_id = $pages_id");
```

instead of

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET 'pagename' = $pagename, 'pagedesc' = $pagedesc, 'pagekey' = $pagekey, 'pagecont' = $pagecont, WHERE 'pages_id' = $pages_id");
```

You were using ' (Single quote) in field name. single quote is used when the data is of type varchar

e.g. If table have field as myField02 varchar2(20), then while inserting query will be

```
INSERT INTO myTable values ('myValue');
```

If the field are not varchar then don't use single quote

```
INSERT INTO myTable values (myValue);
```

Comment: Agreed. If @GT22 wants to add surrounding characters (not necessary unless they're reserved words) use backticks (`), not single quotes (')

Comment: using backticks are not compuslory in field name like OP have as single quote. But if field are of type varchar, OP will have to use single quote while assigning data.

Comment: Than @FahimParkar - You are correct the back ticks did not work, but ' did. Thank you again for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra "," in your SQL statement.

```
agecont, WHERE
```

Comment: Hi @Chin-Boon I've removed that, but it still fails.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the line which has mysql_query:

```
mysql_query("<QUERY GOES HERE>") or die(mysql_error());
```

This will show you the exact error in the query.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I didn't think of that, duh! It tells me "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''pagename' = updatetestpage, 'pagedesc' = updated' at line 1"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not checking whether your query is actually succesful or not. EDIT: Think you got this one.

There are a few syntax errors in your SQL query:

For Example

```
// Your code
UPDATE pages SET 'pagename' = $pagename

// How SQL expects
UPDATE pages SET pagename = '$pagename'
```

Notice the single quotes ONLY around the variables we want to put in.

Re-writing your SQL query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pages 
             SET pagename = '{$pagename}',
                 pagedesc = '{$pagedesc}',
                 agekey   = '{$pagekey}',
                 pagecont = '{$pagecont}' 
             WHERE pages_id = '{$pages_id}'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Note the column names have no ` or ' surrounding them, only the variables you are using to run the update.

EDIT: Answer updated to show op where his errors are

Answer (score 0):

> mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET `pagename` = '$pagename', `pagedesc` =
>   '$pagedesc', `pagekey` = '$pagekey', `pagecont` = '$pagecont' WHERE
>   `pages_id` = $pages_id");

use `(accent) instead of ' in fields and u have extra ,(comma) before where

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your query one the `comma` before where and second you have used `single quotes` for fieldnames. Use backtics instead of single quotes for fieldname. Use this query. Also take care of sql injections. use `mysql_real_escape_string().`

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET `pagename` = $pagename, `pagedesc` = $pagedesc, 
`agekey` = $pagekey, `pagecont` = $pagecont WHERE `pages_id` = $pages_id");
```